# How to create HL7 message ORU_R01 type using HAPI 2.4

Tags: hl7, hapi

I am newbie to HL7. I am trying to construct HL7 message ORU_R01 type using HAPI 2.4. I got incorrect message format when I add **patient details** in the below code; otherwise the format is ok. How to fix this issue? is there any example to construct HL7 ORU message with PID,ORC,OBR and OBX?

**Output without patient**

MSH|^~\&|IM|ABC-ClinPath|ABC-vet|ABC-VetMed|20180412124041||ORU^R01

**Output with patient** (If I comment the patient details in the code)

PID||TEST|||^TESTlinPath|ABC-vet|ABC-VetMed|20180412124041||ORU^R01

```
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.message.ORM_O01;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.HapiContext;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.DefaultHapiContext;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.Parser;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.segment.MSH;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.group.ORM_O01_PATIENT;

public class CreateORUMessage {

private String sendingApplication = "IM";
private String sendingFacility = "ABC-ClinPath";
private String receivingApplication = "ABC-vet";
private String receivingFacility = "ABC-VetMed";


private void createHL7Message(){
    try{
        ORM_O01 order = new ORM_O01();
        //ORU_R01 oru = new ORU_R01();
        // Populate the MSH Segment
        // Example -  MSH|^~\&|HISA_8592|HISF_2603|||200706081131||ADT^A04|HL7O.1.11379|D|2.1
        MSH mshSegment = order.getMSH();
        mshSegment.getFieldSeparator().setValue("|");
        mshSegment.getEncodingCharacters().setValue("^~\\&");
        mshSegment.getSendingApplication().getNamespaceID().setValue(sendingApplication);
        mshSegment.getSendingFacility().getNamespaceID().setValue(sendingFacility);
        mshSegment.getReceivingApplication().getNamespaceID().setValue(receivingApplication);
        mshSegment.getReceivingFacility().getNamespaceID().setValue(receivingFacility);
        mshSegment.getDateTimeOfMessage().getTimeOfAnEvent().setValue("20180412124041");
        mshSegment.getMessageType().getMessageType().setValue("ORU");
        mshSegment.getMessageType().getTriggerEvent().setValue("R01");

        //PID - patient details
        ORM_O01_PATIENT orm_pid = order.getPATIENT();
        orm_pid.getPID().getPid5_PatientName(0).getGivenName().setValue("TEST");
        orm_pid.getPID().getPid2_PatientID().getCx1_ID().setValue("TEST");


     // Now, let's encode the message and look at the output
        HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();
        Parser parser = context.getPipeParser();
        String encodedMessage = parser.encode(order);
        System.out.println("Printing ER7 Encoded Message:");
        System.out.println(encodedMessage);

        //String msg = order.encode();
        //System.out.println(msg);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new CreateORUMessage().createHL7Message();
}
}
```

I tried other way too, but it's not worked :(

```
String msg = order.encode();
System.out.println(msg);
```

Comment: Add the stack trace please.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem most likely is, that the segment separator character in HL7 is `CR`, which just resets the cursor to the start of the line and the next line overwrites the previous one. This only affects writing the message to the console. Writing to file or sending over TCP should be fine without any further conversions.

I had the same problem in an application once, this is my solution below.

```
ORU_R01 outMessage = new ORU_R01();
outMessage.setParser(hapiContext.getPipeParser());

outMessage.initQuickstart("ORU", "R01", "T");
MSH mshSegment = outMessage.getMSH();
mshSegment.getMsh3_SendingApplication().getHd1_NamespaceID().setValue("MIG-TOOL");

/* some code removed */

PID pidSegment = outMessage.getRESPONSE().getPATIENT().getPID();
pidSegment.getPid3_PatientIDInternalID(0).parse(reportData.getPatientId());

/* some more code removed */

LOGGER.trace("Generated message contents:\n" + replaceNewlines(outMessage.encode()));
```

And the code for `replaceNewLines()` is quite simple

```
private static String replaceNewlines(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("\\r", "\n");
}
```

Comment: This should be chosen as the correct answer. This worked thanks!